# Where to add CSS and Javascript directives so they are inserted into the header?

Tags: theming, javascript

I am attempting to make use of a jQuery script that will enable a "slider" or "slideshow" on my Drupal 7 front page. The instructions for the jQuery plugin (called [FlexSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)) say to insert the following items into the header of the page where I want to use the plugin.

```
<!-- Place somewhere in the <head> of your document -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">`</script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

The problem is I don't know where in my template file I place these directives. I am using a custom front page for Drupal so I have a template file named `page--front.tpl.php`. Do the directives go in there or some other location?

Comment: If you're not using Flexslider module, your slider will work on jQuery included in drupal core, but some flexslider plugins, like "animate colors" requires jQuery v 1.5.2 or higher. You can update your core jQuery with this modlule: http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to add the files inside your theme's info file. However you shouldn't need the jquery file, this is included in Drupal core.

```
scripts[] = scripts.js
stylesheets[all][] = style.css
```

Morea bout info files here: http://drupal.org/node/171205

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the [Drupal Flexslider module](http://drupal.org/project/flexslider), no?

Alternatively you could add the files to your theme and your theme .info file, with

```
scripts[] = 'js/flexslider.js'
stylesheets[all][] = flexslider.css
```

path should be relative to the .info file, so if you say js/flexslider.js the flexslider.js file must be inside the js directory in your theme.

Alternatively with a module and [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) and [drupal_add_css](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7)